# Tensorflow Serving client issue

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-serving

I have trained and saved TF model using Keras and able to Convert Keras model(hdf5) to Tensorflow Serving.

setup details where Modle is trained and saved:
Python version : 2.7.5
Keras version :  2.1.4 Using TensorFlow backend.
Tensorflow CPU : 1.5.0

I have Docker image for Tensorflow Serving
When i am trying to run the client with sample_client.py it fails with below error. Can anyone suggest me how to proceed further?

```
/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py:36: FutureWarning:         
Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to 
`np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == 
 np.dtype(float).type`.
 from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
 Using TensorFlow backend.
(60000, 28, 28)
6
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "sample_client.py", line 62, in <module>
main()
File "sample_client.py", line 54, in main
result = stub.Predict(request, request_timeout)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/grpc/beta/_client_adaptations.py", 
line 309, in __call__
self._request_serializer, self._response_deserializer)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/grpc/beta/_client_adaptations.py", 
line 195, in _blocking_unary_unary
raise _abortion_error(rpc_error_call)
grpc.framework.interfaces.face.face.AbortionError: 
AbortionError(code=StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT, details="NodeDef mentions 
attr 'dilations' not in Op<name=Conv2D; signature=input:T, filter:T -> 
output:T; attr=T:type,allowed=[DT_HALF, DT_FLOAT]; attr=strides:list(int); 
attr=use_cudnn_on_gpu:bool,default=true; attr=padding:string,allowed=
["SAME", "VALID"]; attr=data_format:string,default="NHWC",allowed=["NHWC", 
"NCHW"]>; NodeDef: conv2d_1/convolution = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, _output_shapes=
 [[?,26,26,32]], data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], 
 padding="VALID", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true, 
_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_arg_conv2d_1_input_0_0, 
conv2d_1/kernel/read). (Check whether your GraphDef-interpreting binary is 
up to date with your GraphDef-generating binary.).
     [[Node: conv2d_1/convolution = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, _output_shapes=
[[?,26,26,32]], data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="VALID", 
strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true, 
_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_arg_conv2d_1_input_0_0, 
conv2d_1/kernel/read)]]")


sample_client.py:
import numpy
from keras.datasets import mnist
from grpc.beta import implementations
import tensorflow as tf
from predict_client import predict_pb2
from predict_client import prediction_service_pb2
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string("host", "0.0.0.0", "gRPC server host")
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer("port", 9000, "gRPC server port")
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string("model_name", "mnist", "TensorFlow model name")
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer("model_version", -1, "TensorFlow model version")
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_float("request_timeout", 10.0, "Timeout of gRPC     request")
FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

print(numpy.shape(x_train))
idx = 2324
img = x_train[idx,:,:]
label = y_train[idx]
img = numpy.resize(img, (1, 28, 28, 1))
print(label)


def main():
  host = FLAGS.host
  port = FLAGS.port
  model_name = FLAGS.model_name
  model_version = FLAGS.model_version
  request_timeout = FLAGS.request_timeout

  # Generate inference data
  keys = numpy.asarray([1, 2, 3])
  keys_tensor_proto = tf.contrib.util.make_tensor_proto(keys, dtype=tf.int32)
  features_tensor_proto = tf.contrib.util.make_tensor_proto(img,
                                                        dtype=tf.float32)

  # Create gRPC client and request
  channel = implementations.insecure_channel(host, port)
  stub = prediction_service_pb2.beta_create_PredictionService_stub(channel)
  request = predict_pb2.PredictRequest()
  request.model_spec.name = model_name
  if model_version > 0:
    request.model_spec.version.value = model_version
  request.inputs['inputs'].CopyFrom(features_tensor_proto)
  request.model_spec.signature_name = 'predict'
  #request.inputs['features'].CopyFrom(features_tensor_proto)

  # Send request
  result = stub.Predict(request, request_timeout)
  response = numpy.array(result.outputs['outputs'].float_val)
  prediction = numpy.argmax(response)

  print(prediction)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Thanks in Advance

Regards
Latha

Comment: Below is the snippet of Export code:                                                                            
    signature = predict_signature_def(inputs=
    {'inputs':model.input},outputs={'outputs': model.output})
with K.get_session() as sess:
    builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(sess=sess,
                                         tags=[tag_constants.SERVING],
                                         signature_def_map={'predict': signature})

Comment: Would this be because of two different model versions? Like a GPU version on the client side, and a CPU version on the container side?

Comment: I have followed the steps mentioned in https://github.com/amiyapatanaik/tensorflow-serving-docker-image and it fails while running Sample python client.
On my local system i have Tensorflow CPU , python and kears installed. 
Python version : 2.7.5 ,Keras version : 2.1.4 Using TensorFlow backend,Tensorflow CPU : 1.5.0
There is no information on the docker image if its CPU /GPU.
The client fails with the model which is  locally trained , exported and used in docker .
With the exitsing model(https://github.com/amiyapatanaik/tensorflow-serving-docker-image) client does not fail.
Thanks

Comment: The model contains operations names. These names are evolving with most TF versions, and you need the same operations available on client and server side. Do you know what TF version is on client and server?

Comment: The reason for this question is that the error occurs when the client tries serializing your request, and a node definition differs from what is expected.

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the reason that TensorFlow version in the tensorflow_model_server is simply older than 1.5 and hence does not know how to instantiate that operator.

Either try rebuild your model on a sufficiently older TensorFlow release or try creating a tensorflow_model_server with a newer TensorFlow version.

Just follow the steps given here to build the docker with latest source of Tensorflow serving.
https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/docker